# wrap text aroud responsive image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Am trying to wrap some text around an image. i found some code from searching stackoverflow. it works but when window is resized below 1200px the text is not wrapping around, and the image stays on the right.

```
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="zoi_img"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail pull-right" src="img/Asfaleia Zois.jpg" alt="Ασφάλεια Ζωής" width="640" height="450"></div>          
            <h4 class="inline-link-2">Προστασία για εσάς και την οικογένεια σας</h4>
            <p>Μέσα στη λέξη "ζωή" περιλαμβάνεται η ύπαρξη αλλά και η δημιουργία κάποιου. Πράγματα μικρά και μεγάλα που καθορίζουν το στίγμα μας και τα οποία θέλουμε να προστατέψουμε από οποιοδήποτε κίνδυνο μπορεί να τα απειλήσει.</p>
            <p>Η Εθνική σας δίνει τη δυνατότητα να τα προστατέψετε με τα εξειδικευμένα ασφαλιστικά μας προγράμματα</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="item_link" href="#a1">Απλή Ασφάλεια Ζωής</a></li>
                <li><a class="item_link" href="#a2">Απλή Ανανεώσιμη Ασφάλεια Ζωής</a></li>
                <li><a class="item_link" href="#a3">Απλή Μετατρέψιμη Ασφάλεια Ζωής</a></li>
                <li><a class="item_link" href="#a4">Απλή Αναεώσιμη και Μετατρέψιμη Ασφάλεια Ζωής</a></li>
                <li><a class="item_link" href="#a5">Απλή Μειούμενη Ασφάλεια Ζωής</a></li>
            </ul>
            <p>Ακόμη μπορείτε να ενισχύσετε περισσότερο τα ασφαλιστήρια σας μέσα από την πλήρη σειρά Συμπληρωματικών Ωφελημάτων που προσφέρουμε.</p>
            <h4 style="color:#d65150" id="a1">Απλή Πρόσκαιρη Ασφάλεια - Term Insurance</h4>
            <p>Η παραδοσιακή αυτή ασφάλιση έχει σαν σκοπό την εξασφάλιση των δικαιούχων από το θάνατο του ασφαλισμένου. Σε θάνατο του ασφαλισμένου οι δικαιούχοι λαμβάνουν το ποσό του κεφαλαίου ασφάλισης. Στην λήξη δεν υπάρχει ποσό καταβολής καθότι το συμβόλαιο αυτό δεν δημιουργεί αξίες εξαγοράς.</p>
            <h4 style="color:#d65150" id="a2">Απλή Ανανεώσιμη Πρόσκαιρη Ασφάλεια - Renewable Term Insurance</h4>
            <p>Η παραδοσιακή αυτή ασφάλιση έχει σαν σκοπό την εξασφάλιση των δικαιούχων από το θάνατο του ασφαλισμένου. Σε θάνατο του ασφαλισμένου οι δικαιούχοι λαμβάνουν το ποσό του κεφαλαίου ασφάλισης. Στην λήξη δεν υπάρχει ποσό καταβολής καθότι το συμβόλαιο αυτό δεν δημιουργεί αξίες εξαγοράς.</p>
            <h4 style="color:#d65150" id="a3">Απλή Μετατρέψιμη Πρόσκαιρη Ασφάλεια - Convertible Term Insurance</h4>
            <p>Η παραδοσιακή αυτή ασφάλιση έχει σαν σκοπό την εξασφάλιση των δικαιούχων από το θάνατο του ασφαλισμένου. Σε θάνατο του ασφαλισμένου οι δικαιούχοι λαμβάνουν το ποσό του κεφαλαίου ασφάλισης. Στην λήξη δεν υπάρχει ποσό καταβολής καθότι το συμβόλαιο αυτό δεν δημιουργεί αξίες εξαγοράς.</p>
            <h4 style="color:#d65150" id="a4">Απλή Ανανεώσιμη ή Μετατρέψιμη Πρόσκαιρη Ασφάλεια - Renewable or Convertible Term Insurance</h4>
            <p>Η παραδοσιακή αυτή ασφάλιση έχει σαν σκοπό την εξασφάλιση των δικαιούχων από το θάνατο του ασφαλισμένου. Σε θάνατο του ασφαλισμένου οι δικαιούχοι λαμβάνουν το ποσό του κεφαλαίου ασφάλισης. Στην λήξη δεν υπάρχει ποσό καταβολής καθότι το συμβόλαιο αυτό δεν δημιουργεί αξίες εξαγοράς.</p>
            <h4 style="color:#d65150" id="a5">Απλή Μειούμενη Ασφάλεια</h4>
            <p>Η παραδοσιακή αυτή ασφάλιση έχει σαν σκοπό την εξασφάλιση των δικαιούχων από το θάνατο του ασφαλισμένου. Σε θάνατο του ασφαλισμένου οι δικαιούχοι λαμβάνουν το ποσό του κεφαλαίου ασφάλισης. Στην λήξη δεν υπάρχει ποσό καταβολής καθότι το συμβόλαιο αυτό δεν δημιουργεί αξίες εξαγοράς.</p>
        </div>
```

Now i used this media query

```
@media(max-width:1200px) {
    #zoi_img img{float:none!important;}
}
```

and the image is fixed from flowing on the right **locally on my pc** but text is not wrapping around and is there another way to do it without using the above css media query

---------->[Demo Link](http://kleanthous.comlu.com/Asfaleia-Zois.html)<----------

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add "float : right;" style to div as below.

```
<div class="" style="float:right;"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail pull-right" src="img/Asfaleia Zois.jpg" alt="Ασφάλεια Ζωής" width="640" height="450"></div>
```

And then remove "display: inline-block;" style from "inline-link-2".
Also remove "col-md-12" too.

After removing "col-md-12", For Small screen size issue you can use media query and make imahe width smaller to wrap some text around it.

```
@media(max-width: 991px) {
    img{width:300px !important;}
}
```

[Here the sample. Resize and check it.](http://codepen.io/BishanMeddegoda/pen/WwvOQN)

Comment: from 991 until 1200 is ok but under 991 is still floating on the right with no text wrapping

Comment: now is not working on mobile. U sure u know what ur doing man :) the col-md-12 is supposed to be there so that responsiveness is working

Comment: if its 12 then how you wrap text around it? With having col-md-12 you can't wrap around it cus it use all the area in bootstrap we only have 12 grids. So you have to remove it if you want to wrap text around it.